# require_once(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0

Tags: php, wordpress

I know this error is dicussed often already, but I just can't use require or include in my function.php(xampp) without this error on the top and I don't have a php.ini file. I don't even want one, if not necessary!

I just want to include a second php file in the fuction.php. Come on that can't be so hard...

That's what I used.

```
require_once (get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/index.php');
```

(result: http://localhost/werkstatt/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/index.php)

I mean in this case the index.php would be inluded anyway which leads me to the second question. Why or how are some standard files like index.php already inluded?

Comment: This is a (rather important) security feature. You should not include files via HTTP. And if they are on the same server, you don't have to. Just use relative paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

index.php is not included at all, this is the entry point to PHP code execution and it is defined in your webserver config (not really precise, but should give you an idea).

The PHP file you want to include, is it on the same server? If so, you need to include it by its filename, and not by its URL. I understand you want to include another PHP file which is part of your theme.
I don't know much about wordpress and what helper functions it defines, but this seems to be the one you need to use: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory/.

If it is not placed an the same server, then you just should not do this.

Comment: include (get_template_directory().'/index.php'); 
Works pretty good for me mate. Thanks a lot!